# Can't execute cd /var/www inside docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting this error:

```
/run.sh: 3: cd: can't cd to /var/www
```

However when I run an interactive shell I can see that my current directory is /var/www.

[image]

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer update
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh


EXPOSE 80

COPY ./docker/run.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/run.sh"]
```

And this is the content of my run.sh:

[image]

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /var/www

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache

/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
```

As you can see guys I'm trying to run a php laravel application. I don't know why happens this, I will appreciate any idea to fix this issue. Thanks so much.

PD: this the permissions of run.sh which is inside the docker/ directory of my laravelapp:

[image]

```
ls -ldh /var/www/
```

Output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jun  8 17:45 /var/www/
```

Comment: I think you have permissions issues, could you show us what user and group the `run.sh` file has? And I think you are running everything as `root` as you are never specifying a new user in the `Dockerfile`, you are just creating it. But even if that is the case, you should not have issues

Comment: you copy and chown into `/var/www` but you don't actually change the owner of `/var/www` itself. If you do `CMD chown www:www-data /var/www` it may work

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for the comment. I have updated the questions see at the bottom

Comment: @apokryfos I added that in my dockerfile but the problem remains. https://imgur.com/a/MvQpSvg

Comment: Please don't post the output of the terminal as images, copy and paste it as text. Please run `ls -ldh /var/www/` into the container and share the output, it will display the permissions and the owner.

Comment: @AL the output is: drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jun  8 17:45 /var/www/ I don't kwno why is root the owner.

Comment: Im using caprover free open source PaaS to deploy my applications. This uses docker.

Comment: @A.L I added: RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www and now the permission changed to: drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4.0K Jun  8 18:11 /var/www/ But the cd command is not working continues the same error.

Comment: Also try changing `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`

Answer (score 0):

I believe `COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www` should be `COPY --chown=www:www. /var/www`

The user and the group should both be `www` for the chown flag.

Also, in your `RUN chown www:www-data /var/www` you screenshotted that should be updated to along with recursively chowning like `RUN chown -R www:www /var/www`